Why does the events in RRule offset by whole 1 day in cases where timezone conversion to UTC was next day?
I have a calendar that shows the recurring events using the RRule. I am on PST timezone so the calendar is also on PST.
When I create a RRule with dtstart where the PST to UTC conversion DOES NOT ADD a day, it works fine showing events on Friday (recurEvents_1 in code below).
But When I create a RRule with dtstart where the PST to UTC conversion ADDS a day, it shows the events as they are on Thursday, offsetting a day incorrectly (recurEvents_2 in code below).
const dtstart_1 = new Date(Date.UTC(2024, 5, 14, 23, 29, 0));
// Fri Jun 14 2024 16:29:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)

// The 2nd dtstart_2 is 1 hour more than above which will be the NEXT day in UTC
// but SAME day in PST (Pacific)
const dtstart_2 = new Date(Date.UTC(2024, 5, 15, 0, 29, 0)); 
// Fri Jun 14 2024 17:29:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)


// Both the RRule below are exactly the same, except the dtstart
const rrule_1 = new RRule({
  dtstart: new Date(dtstart_1), 
  freq: RRule.WEEKLY,
  byweekday: RRule.FR, // Note this
  count: 2,
})             
const recurEvents_1 = rrule_1.all();

const rrule_2 = new RRule({
  dtstart: new Date(dtstart_2),  
  freq: RRule.WEEKLY,
  byweekday: RRule.FR, // Note this
  count: 2,
})             
const recurEvents_2 = rrule_2.all();


Here the result of above first recurEvents_1 yields events on Friday, which is correct.
{
    Fri Jun 14 2024 16:29:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time),
    Fri Jun 21 2024 16:29:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
}

But, on the second recurEvents_2, it yields events on Thursdays, which is incorrect as there is byweekday: RRule.FR on both so event should be on Fridays Only. But the time is correct, just one day offset.
Interestingly, if I change byweekday to Saturday(RRule.SA), then the events show up on Friday.
{
    Thu Jun 20 2024 17:29:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time),
    Thu Jun 27 2024 17:29:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)
}

I have tried playing around with timezones and offsets but cannot make this work. I need to be able to have code that caters to both cases above and gives events correctly on Fridays in PST even when the PST to UTC conversion adds a day.
